# Can I print debug messages to the browser console in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I'm testing my Javascript code, I often use console.log to write messages to the browser console. I find it a convenient place to check for these messages.

Is it possible to output messages to the browser console from Ruby files within your Rails project? (E.g. from a method in the model)

Comment: You can check https://github.com/rails/web-console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple. Just call `puts 'your debug message'` and it will be printed to where the server is logging. For instance, if you are running the rails server only by running `rails s` on a terminal, the output of `puts` will be on this same terminal. If you need more 'power' to debug, you should consider using IDE's like [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) to debug your code. Thus, you can place breakpoints and see all the application state.

Comment: For the record, the question asked about printing to the browser log and the answer is no.  Rails code executes on the server and log messages are stored/viewed there.  Javascript executes in the browser so logs are viewed in the browser.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `console.log()` in your views:

```
#view.html.erb
<script>
    console.log("Message");
</script>
```

If you want to log in your Model, try:

```
Rails.logger.debug "message!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, as cstrutton mentioned printing to the browser log is not possible. But this is something I tend to do which may help others in the same situation.

Say for example, I only want to display my debug params on my page if my :commit == "Search". I would do something like this:

In my helper file.

```
    def view_logging
        if params[:commit] == "Search"
            debug params
        else
            # add whatever you want here if not true
        end
    end
```

Now inside my view page, I would just simply add the helper method defined.

```
<%= view_logging %>
```